# What is the minimum number of painted edges in the chessboard?

Tags: combinatorics

Some edges of the squares of an 8×8 chessboard are painted red. What is the minimum number of edges that must be painted, so that each square has at least two red edges? What is the meaning of this question? What should be my approach to solve it?

Comment: The meaning of the question is, what is the minimum number of edges of the chessboard that must be painted red, so that each square has at least two red edges? What part don't you understand?

Comment: Hint: You've got to walk before you can run. First try to figure out the answer for a smaller chessboard, like $2\times2$ or $2\times4$ or $4\times4$, then try to extend your ideas to the $8\times8$ board.

Comment: One pattern would be to paint all the edges.  Clearly every square gets at least two edges painted, in fact all four.  How many edges is that?  Another would be to paint all the vertical edges. Can you see that every square gets two edges painted?  How many edges is that? Can you improve on this?

Comment: For instance, the $2\times2$ board has $4$ squares, each square has $4$ edges, but some edges are shared between two squares, so there are only $12$ different edges. Now, by wisely choosing which edges to paint, you can paint just $4$ of the $12$ edges red, so that each square has two red edge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theoretical minimum is achieved when each square has exactly two red edges and no edge that is in the border is painted red. In this case $64$ edges must be colored. Prove it is possible.

Here is a coloring that works:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** Put a [rook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rook_(chess)) on the board, say on a corner square. Can you make a series of rook moves that traverses every square on the board once and only once, and returns to its starting point? Now what can you say about the set of edges that the rook crosses?